# Crashlytics Android Studio Can't run: NoClassDefFoundError: javax/swing/SwingUtilities

Tags: android, crashlytics

I'm working with android studio 0.5.4. 
I try to install crashlytics plugin. I have download it and got CrashlyticsAndroidStudioPlugin.zip. I have installed it `setttings > Plugins > Install plugin form disk > "OK".` the crashlytics button has appeared on the toolbar. But when I select myAndroidProject then click "the red crashlytics button" I got these error message:

```
 [ 596982]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - javax/swing/SwingUtilities
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/swing/SwingUtilities
        at com.crashlytics.tools.ide.app.Launcher.asyncShowShell(Launcher.java:1
 16)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.intellij.app.CrashlyticsBridgeImpl.asyncShowPar
entedShell(CrashlyticsBridgeImpl.java:179)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.intellij.app.CrashlyticsBridgeImpl.access$000(C
rashlyticsBridgeImpl.java:36)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.intellij.app.CrashlyticsBridgeImpl$2.setSelecte
d(CrashlyticsBridgeImpl.java:168)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.intellij.actions.CrashlyticsAction.setSelected(
CrashlyticsAction.java:59)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ToggleAction.actionPerformed(Toggle
Action.java:42)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAwar
e(ActionUtil.java:164)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.actionPerformed(A
ctionButton.java:170)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.performAction(Act
ionButton.java:133)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.processMouseEvent
(ActionButton.java:311)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898
   )
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)

        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
main.java:75)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
main.java:86)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
main.java:75)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.jav
a:697)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:520)

        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.
java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.swing.SwingUtilities not foun
d by com.crashlytics.tools.intellij.core [1]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDele
gation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1460)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringIm
pl.java:72)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadCla
ss(BundleWiringImpl.java:1843)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 42 more
[ 597364]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio (Preview) 0.5
.4  Build #AI-135.1101912
[ 597365]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0
[ 597366]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server
VM
[ 597367]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Vendor: Oracle Corporation
[ 597368]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Windows 7
[ 597368]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action: Actions.Crashly
 tics.CrashlyticsAction
```

Can Anybody help me? have you ever got these error message?
FYI: I'm using windows 7 and using `java jdk1.8.0.`

Comment: Same issue for me . I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and jdk 1.8.0 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been looking around and I think Java 8 has something to do to it. I see a few people are having this issue. The common thing people are saying is that they have Java 8. I just checked out Java 1.7.0_55. Its seems to fix the issue.

Comment: it works. thank you @slai47. 
I try to install my old jdk: jdk1.6.0_27, and don't forget to change the path in windows environment variable, JAVA_HOME variable that was set when we were installing android studio, change it from jdk 1.8.0 path to my jdk1.6.0 path. And it works.

Comment: I solved with removing Oracle Java 8 and then: sudo aptitude install openjdk-7-jdk